# Numerical gradient divergence in GSL

Tags: c++, algorithm, numerical-methods, gsl, minimization

I am using the conjugate gradient method

```
gsl_multimin_fdfminimizer_conjugate_fr
```

in the GSL package to minimize a function f. This method requires derivatives, so I have passed the derivative in two ways:

```
static void dfun(const gsl_vector *v, void *params, gsl_vector *df) {
  return fun(x+epsilon)-f(x)/epsilon
}
```

and another way which is less direct but faster. Both functions return the same values for the gradient in all variables, up to a precision of ~10 digits. However, when I run the minimization using the latter, I do not reach the minimum and the minimizer returns 27: unable to get a better result. When using dfun as the derivative, I converge to the correct minimum.

What may be causing this behavior, and what steps can I take to fix it?